# Assign a pcap_t* File Descriptor to a Chunk of Memory?

Tags: c, pcap, file-descriptor

I’ve written a C program which write a valid PCAP file into a malloc’ed chunk of memory:

```
u_char* myPCAP = writePCAP( ... );
```

The program works wonderfully, and if I write myPCAP to a file, I can read that file in Wireshark and everything.  So I know that everything is working.
But now, I want to assign myPCAP a `pcap_t*` file descriptor and pass that FD to another program.  (nDPI, for those who are curious.)  How could I do this?  I was hoping this would work:

```
pcap_t* pcap = fdopen( ((int*)myPCAP), "r" );
```

But:

```
me@ubuntu:/home/me#  make all
gcc -g -fPIC -DPIC -I../src/include -g -O2 -c MyCode.c -o MyCode.o
MyCode.c: In function ‘msgHandler’:
MyCode.c:750:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fdopen’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  pcap_t* pcap = (pcap_t*)fdopen( ((int*)myPCAP), "r" );
                                  ^
In file included from MyCode.c:16:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:265:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 extern FILE *fdopen (int __fd, const char *__modes) __THROW __wur;
              ^~~~~~
g++ -g -fPIC -DPIC -I../src/include -g -O2 MyCode.o libndpiReader.a -o ndpiReader ../src/lib/libndpi.a -lpcap  -lpthread -lm
me@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

Anyone see a solution?  There’s got to be a way, right?  Thank you.

Comment: The argument to `fdopen()` has to be a file descriptor, which comes from the kernel.

Comment: File descriptors aren't pointers.

Comment: You can't treat memory as a file descriptor. Why don't you use a pipe?

Comment: @Barmar  I'm open to any solution.  Can you pipe in a C program?

Comment: Yes, use the `pipe()` system call.

Comment: You write the PCAP data to one end of the pipe, pass the other end to the process that wants to read the file.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting!  I am not writing the function that will be receiving the PCAP, so I may not have that option.  But I'll look into it for sure.  Thank you!

Comment: The other function doesn't know it's a pipe, it just reads from the FD.

Comment: @Barmar  Interesting... I'll try it.  Thanks!