# Can I Submit Data-In-Memory to pcap_loop()?

Tags: c, pcap

Using [this link](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/blog/programming/multithread/server.c) as a guide, I’ve written a C program which writes a PCAP file to disk.  The PCAP contains complete Ethernet/IP/TCP packets, with payload.  And after my program is done, I can manually read the generated PCAP files in Wireshark, so I believe the code works great.  Here’s the pseudocode:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv ){

    u_char* pcapData = generatePCAPData();     // malloc()’s and creates the PCAP
                                               // file as a chunk of memory

    int sizeOfPcapData = getPcapLen( pcapData );

    FILE *fd = fopen( "myPcapFile.pcacp", "w" );
    fwrite( pcapData, sizeOfPcapData, 1, fd );
    fclose( fd );

    free( pcapData );

    return 1;
}
```

There is another program which does packet analysis and accepts PCAP files as input.  (That program is nDPI, for anyone who is interested.)  When I dig into the other program’s source code, I see that it uses `pcap_loop()` to analyze the PCAP input.  That makes sense.  And when I manually submit my written-to-disk PCAP files to this program, the program analyzes them perfectly.

But writing my PCAPs to disk and then reading them from disk is too time-consuming.  I’d love a solution that takes that `u_char* pcapData` in memory and submits it directly to `pcap_loop()`.  In theory, this should work.  I thought perhaps I could use a C `tmpfile()` to do the trick.

But my attempt segfaulted, right on the call to `pcap_loop()`.  So I tried calling pcap_loop in my own code, just to see what happened.  Here’s the modification:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv ){

    u_char* pcapData = generatePCAPData();         // as before

    int sizeOfPcapData = getPcapLen( pcapData );   // as before

    FILE* myTmpFile = tmpfile();
    if( myTmpFile == NULL )  return -1;

    fwrite( pcapData, sizeOfPcapData, 1, myTmpFile );

    if(pcap_loop( (pcap_t*)myTmpFile, 1, &myCallback, NULL) < 0){
        printf("ERROR!\n");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The above code segfaults right on the call to `pcap_loop()`.  The callback function is never reached.  When I try to step into `pcap_loop()` on my debugger (GDB), the code segfaults immediately.  So all I really know is that `pcap_loop()` is choking on the in-memory version of my PCAP file.  I wish I knew why.

So…  my approach is wrong.  Has anyone ever dealt with an issue like this before?  I can’t believe I’m the first.  Thanks.

(FYI, I am coding on an Ubuntu platform, using GCC 7.4.0)

FULL DISCLOSURE :: I've also posted this issue [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/iq7hs0/is_is_possible_to_submit_a_pcap_to_pcap_loop_when/).

Comment: Is FILE the same thing as pcap_t? If not, then why are you casting FILE* to pcap_t*?

Comment: @user253751  Good question.  I believe... but am not certain... that a pcap_t is the file descriptor for a PCAP file.  This post led me to that conclusion:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003690/what-is-pcap-pcap-t-errbufpcap-errbuf-size

Comment: If a pcap_t was the file descriptor for a PCAP file, they would use FILE* instead of making their own type.

Comment: @user253751  Hmmmm...  Yes, I do believe you are correct.  I guess to think otherwise was a bad assumption on my part.  Dangit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `pcap_t` is a descriptor for a supplier of packets.

Those packets can come from a file *OR* they can come from a capture device.

*If* the `pcap_t` was opened with a call such as `pcap_open_offline()`, which opens a pcap file, it refers to a file, but it is *NOT* a `FILE *`.  (And that's not what I intended to say with the post you say led you to that conclusion; please re-read it, more carefully.  As a core libpcap developer, I know for certain what a `pcap_t` is - and isn't.)

If you want to directly submit packets to nDPI, without writing out a file and having it read the file, if nDPI can read from a pipe, the best way to do this is by writing to a pipe, as [the comments on another question you asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784671/assign-a-pcap-t-file-descriptor-to-a-chunk-of-memory) suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following this thread...  The solution was to use a function in the <pcap.h> library, `pcap_fopen_offline()`.  This was my solution:

```
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv ){

    u_char* pcapData = generatePCAPData();         // as before

    int sizeOfPcapData = getPcapLen( pcapData );   // as before

    FILE* myTmpFile = tmpfile();
    if( myTmpFile == NULL )  return -1;

    fwrite( pcapData, sizeOfPcapData, 1, myTmpFile );

    // ****************************************************
    pcap_t* myPcapFile = pcap_fopen_offline( myTmpFile, errBuff );
    // ****************************************************

    if(pcap_loop( myPcapFile, 1, &myCallback, NULL) < 0){
        printf("ERROR!\n");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: nDPI is a library, not a program, and it doesn't use pcap; some of the *examples* provided nDPI, showing how to *use* nDPI, such as example/ndpiReader.c and example/ndpiSimpleIntegration.c, do use it. Presumably `myCallback()` performs processing similar to what this examples do, calling the nDPI routines?

Comment: @user13951124  Correct.  I wasn't able to figure out how to use nDPI as a library because the documentation is really minimual, and I've never done coding like this before.  But I saw that ndpiReader.c input PCAP files, and decided to modify that program for my needs.